# How the printf function works in C programming?

Tags: c, printf

I wrote this C program.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int k=35;
  printf("\n%d %d %d",k==35,k=50,k>40);
  return 0;
}
```

and got this output.

> 0 50 0

Now,  I am thinking about how the printf function worked and why the output is 0 50 0.

Comment: You should never write that. The order in which the arguments of printf are evaluated is undefined. So it can be that or 1 50 1 or 1 50 0 or 0 50 1.

Comment: Valid output would also include nasal demons.

Comment: The output is `0 50 0` because the output can be *anything,* since this is undefined behaviour. In fact, it's well within its rights to delete all your files other than `derisive_laughter.mp3` (since it will then proceed to play that through your audio subsystem) :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I get that you're trying to drive home the UB point, but realistically the output won't _anything_. It will be one of the six possible orders in which those arguments can be evaluated.

Comment: @Carey, you could just as easily say "Realistically it'll go left to right as one might expect on reading". The whole *point* about UB is that you can make *no* assumptions on what will happen. Yes, it will *probably* act in one of a limited number of ways but you would be better off assuming it will be far more damaging, so that you're very unlikely to do it again :-)

Comment: There is no use,case for such 'clever' code.  If you do not write it, you cannot be confused by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are invoking undefined behavior by modifying `k` and using its value in the same statement, before a sequence point.

While *any* output is legal and valid, it is possible to understand why `0 50 0` happens in this case:

When a C function is called, its parameters can be evaluated in ***any*** order, but they are *often* evaluated in reverse order (right-most-first, left-most-last).

This is ***not*** guaranteed, but is frequently true.

So the 4 parameters are evaluated as:

1.) `k>40`  (false / `0`, because `k` is 35)
2.) `k=50`  (assign 50 to `k`, and evaluate to 50)
3.) `k==35` (false / `0`, because k is 50, which is not 35)
4.) `"\n%d %d %d"`  (string literal)

Then `printf` prints its parameters: `0, 50, 0`

Comment: "but is frequently true" - more importantly, it's almost certainly true *for this particular question* :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

1. There's no rule to say which order the arguments in a function call (such as when calling `printf`) are evaluated.  It could be left-to-right, right-to-left, or some other order.
2. In an expression like this, where you both modify `k` (`k = 50`) *and* use its value (`k == 35`, `k > 40`), there's no rule to say whether the old or the new value is used.  (And this uncertainty persists regardless of the order of evaluation.)

Because of the second problem, this expression (this `printf` call) is *undefined*.  It can do anything, even something wildly inexplicable.

If you're calling `printf` (or any function) on arguments which have "side effects" like this (that is, where an argument is something like `k = 50`, which not only provides a value to pass to the function, but also makes some other change as well, in this case updating `k`'s value), you need to break things up so that the behavior becomes predictable.  In the case of printing several values, it's easy -- just use several, separate `printf` calls:

```
printf("%d ", k == 35);
printf("%d ", k = 50);
printf("%d\n", k > 40);
```

Now the behavior is well-defined, and will probably be what you expected.